# RewriteRule URL with or without last character

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Example:

User1 has alias: Torstensson.

User2 has alias: Degefors.

I need to use a URL that adds a 's' to all alias. But I can not send User1s alias with a 's' at the end as that will not be recognized as the correct user on the destination page. User1 do not have 's' at the end of its alias so that wont work.

So the URL:

```
 http://somewhere.se/Torstenssons-galleri/konstverk/konstverk
```

"with a added 's' in alias"
should go to:

```
 http://somewhere.se/galleri.konstverk.php?alias=Torstensson&seoname=konstverk
```

"without the 's' in alias"

And the URL:

```
 http://somewhere.se/Degefors-galleri/konstverk/konstverk
```

"no change to alias"

should go to:

```
 http://somewhere.se/galleri.konstverk.php?alias=Degefors&seoname=konstverk
```

"no change to alias"

The Rule I have do not work because the catched group for the alias will be wrong if I send alias that ends with 's'. I do not want to add a extra 's' to those alias as that will not be correct to read.

RewriteRule today:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)s-galleri/konstverk/(.*)$ /galleri.konstverk.php?alias=$1&seoname=$2
```

Can this be solved with RewriteRules? Do I need 2 Rewriterules with and without the 's'?

Comment: Anyone know how to solve this? I have tried using 2 RewriteRules but still not working.

Comment: I solved it with a seperate column in my database that had the correct linktext with or without an 's'. But if someone knows how to fix with RewriteRule, please share :)